# Httphandler with .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-standard, .net-6.0

I had a frustrating meeting with one of middle managers who was insisting that our existing `HttpHandler`s should be migrated to .NET 6 or at least 5.

We have 62 `HttpHandler` and A few `HttpModule`. They are configured in web.config (IIS) and an HttpModule decides which Handler should takeover the traffic. `HttpModule` is configured via a few pages to reroute traffic. This means I don't need to shutdown IIS to change a HttpHandler or restart the whole application to change a route.

I am not talking about converting code to .NET core middleware, we still want to keep the handlers and modules but modify the project to compile with .NET 6.

I have searched for this before and did it again to be sure and I haven't been able to find a single reference to creating HttpHandler or even HttpModule in .NET 5 or 6 (or even Core) documentation. As far as I know .net core doesn't use HttpHandler since having IIS is optional.

I like to know if it is even possible to build a HttpHandler or HttpModule using .NET 5 or 6?

Comment: @Markus, Thank you for comment but, I addressed that in 3rd paragraph. you cannot add a new middleware to application without shutting it down first (recompile all of the code again) but you can add new handlers to application without shutting down the application by just adding a single line to web.config.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those HttpHandlers and HttpModules are built on .NET Framework and have to run thereon. Recompiling them for the .NET Core line would not work because System.Web was never migrated. The whole point of ASP.NET Core was to get away from the technical debt of the original ASP.NET, but IIS is still rooted in .NET Framework. The manager is just chasing buzzwords.

Comment: So you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

Comment: @madreflection, That is exactly why I had a frustrating day. All the problem started when they decided to call .net core as .net 5 and .net 6. just like usb3 gen2 v2. My manager thinks since it is 5 and 6, then must be better than 4! I wouldn't call it technical debt. IMHO Middleware implemented in .NET core was and still is a half backed idea of how middleware supposed to work. With middleware I should be able to swap in/out parts of system without breaking the chain (differs from functionality). With .NET core implementation you have to compile the whole chain again.

Comment: @Eldar, yes Eldar I have. Markus who deleted his comment also suggested the same article (which I explained again, why we don't want to use Microsoft middleware architecture), with our implementation I can short circuit a module or redirect the traffic to another handler but with .net core middleware that is not possible without changing code and re-compiling it. As an alternate we could increase number of micro-services in our system which only adds to complexity and not functionality.

Comment: Well, it actually *is* technical debt. OWIN was the start of their attempt to address the problems, and ASP.NET Core took that model beyond what System.Web could support. Anyway, the manager just needs to be educated. Yeah, calling it ".NET 5" is a little confusing, but at least there wasn't a ".NET Core 4"... that would've been 100 times worse and they knew it. That's why they skipped 4. ASP.NET Core middleware is what it is because the host is separate from IIS now since it can't depend on IIS and be cross-platform.

Comment: The fact is that if you need to be able to add/remove modules on the fly, updating to the ASP.NET Core middleware is simply not the solution. If your manager can't understand that, then he's setting you up for failure.

Comment: Actually, it's pretty possible but not the way you think. You can dump all the middleware in the startup. And each middleware checks if it is active or not by checking an in-memory state (let's say a singleton service) or using Redis to set that state out of the process. So every middleware checks if it will run or not according to that central state. That way you can configure how your middleware act. Controlling your routes via an interface should be better than modifying an XML file?

Comment: @madreflection, I agree with you, but when a new manager joins company and insist in making "improvements" and "changes" then things become complicated.

Comment: @Eldar, As you also mentioned Middlewares need to be added to the project and compiled and deployed to server. I can add new modules and handlers to application at anytime (with reflection). when changing web.config, requests that are in progress will continue but new requests will use new code. with middleware, one shutdown to change the application (assuming you could do it without shutting down IIS) all requests in progress will be terminated too and require additional error checking levels.

Comment: With a new system that doesn't rely on IIS, I would go with multiple applications, a router application, a configuration app, a monitoring app and lots of processor apps. But I needed a second voice to mine to prove that you cannot have IIS httpModules and Handlers with .NET 5 or 6 or in other words, "You cannot milk a male cow"!

Comment: This is a kind of "moral hazard"... the manager expects you to do something that's not possible, but does not bear the consequences for "your" failure to do the impossible thing.

Comment: In theory you can make a custom "PluginMiddleware" which will monitor config and dynamically load new custom handlers (not sure about unloading though and those are definitely not HttpHandlers/Modules). But I would say it is quite a hacky solution and your "new system" approach is much better.